# Creating scratch R files

Tags: files, ess, r

Often I want to create a temporary [R](https://www.r-project.org/) file and don't want to save the file or name the file. Is there a way to achieve this outside of using `C-x C-f` and naming a file? For example, in VSCode or Rstudio I can just create a new file (with just a `Command + N`, but don't need to actually name them or save them to starting using R. Is this possible in Emacs? For example, can I create a keyboard shortcut that creates a temporary file with an arbitrary name (maybe `R_date_timestamp.R`) in some temporary directory or a similar solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a buffer without an associated file.

```
(defun ess-r-mode-scratch ()
  "Create or switch to a scratch buffer in ess-r-mode"
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*ess-r-mode-scratch*"))
  (ess-r-mode))
```

You can bind it to your preferred key, for e `C-c n`

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c n")
                #'ess-r-mode-mode-scratch)
```

Your question inspired me to create the following more general function. With this one buffer will have the same major mode of the buffer where the function is called

```
(defun this-mode-scratch ()
  "Create or switch to a scratch buffer in the current major mode"
  (interactive)
  (let ((this-mode major-mode))
    (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create (format "*%s-scratch*" this-mode)))
    (funcall this-mode)))
```

Comment: Wow, this is fantastic! This is exactly what I'm looking for! How can I also make this specific to `ess-r-mode`, do I just need to change all references to `this-mode`?

Comment: If you want the created buffer to always be in `ess-r-mode`, yes, just directly put `ess-r-mode` instead of `this-mode`. If what you want is being able to call `this-mode-scratch` only in `ess-r-mode`, you can use `(define-key ess-r-mode-map (kbd "C-c n") 'this-mode-scratch)`.

Comment: If you need always the same mode the function can be simpler, see edit

Answer (score 2):

If you want your temporary file to always have the same name, you can use the following command :

```
(defun create-r-temp-file ()
  "Create an empty temporary R file."
  (interactive)
  (find-file-noselect "/your/temp/R/file"))
```

Which will create a temporary file and an associated buffer, but won't automatically switch to that buffer.

On Linux, you can place temporary files in `/tmp`, since you mentioned "`Command + N`" I believe you use macOS and I don't know if something similar exists. But you can still delete it yourself by adding the following :

```
(shell-command "rm -f /your/temp/R/file")
```

to a hook run before exiting Emacs. Or by calling `rm -f /your/temp/R/file` in a script run before shutting down your machine.

Comment: This is really close, thanks! I have the following now                                           `(defun create-r-temp-file ()
  "Create an empty temporary R file."
  (interactive)
  (find-file-noselect (concat "/r_temp/tmp_" (format-time-string "%Y%m%d_%s") ".R")))`                                                                                                                         How can I have this file get focus in a new buffer without needing to navigate to it?

Comment: Use `find-file` instead of `find-file-noselect`?